# SQL Server Select Query - Specifying server as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 2 servers - one production, one test/development. I wanted to run some SQL checks and updates against production data but write the changes to test/development server, so people wouldn't see the changes.

Using SQL Server Management studio, I ran the cursor with the checks and updates in it. I was actively connected to test/development. However, I wrote my queries as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM [Production_Server].[Production_DB].[schema].[table]
```

I was under the impression this would look at the production server, however, it did not. It looks at the test/development server. I have access/rights in both environments.

Is there something I overlooked permission wise to get this to work? Or is just how it is intended to work?

Comment: Do you have a linked server named `Production_Server`? Are you sure it's pointing to the server you think it is?

Comment: To make this possible, you need to create a server link on the test server to be able to talk to the production one, as suggested one comment above. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: No I do not have a linked server for production.   I am sure I specified the correct server in my query.   I did analyze the results against production and that was where I was finding inconsistencies.   I checked the test/dev server and the checks were made against the test/dev data.

Comment: So I attempted to make a linked server and it says it already exists.   But I can't see it in studio.   Shouldn't matter that they are both SQL servers and on the same network right?

Comment: After running exec sp_linkedservers.  I found out the prod server is a linked server to the test/dev server.

Comment: there you go, problem solved :)

Comment: So it's a permissions thing, that the query doesn't go query the prod server?

Answer (score 0):

"[Production_Server]" must be the wrong linked server name.

Run the below sproc to find the correct value to use

```
exec sp_linkedservers
```